# swapping in javascript without split

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
text left - text right
```

How to swap right to left using jquery? str pos is not so good because the parttern is not always fix. It could be `somethingleft-somethingright`

Comment: Why not just use split()?

Comment: @user3522738, is separator always going to be `-` hyphen ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var before = "text left - text right";

var separator = " - ";
var regex = new RegExp("(.*)(" + separator + ")(.*)");
var replace = "$3$2$1";

var after = before.replace(regex, replace);

document.write(after);
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Why doesn't it? It swaps strings without using split.

Comment: @XtraSimplicity: in a good answer it's required to explain your code and why is it working.

Comment: @Qiu, perhaps; but it is still a valid answer. I'm unsure as to why Darko Z feels it isn't even an answer.

Comment: @XtraSimplicity that's an automated comment which is unfortunately the closest to "Your answer may or may not work but it's not very useful without an explanation".

Comment: Oh okay; it might be beneficial to have some way for users to differentiate between Automated and Manual comments. :)

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with?:

```
var string = "text left - text right";
var newString = string.split("-").reverse().join(" - ");
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `String.replace()` and `RegExp` for this task;

```js
var swap = function(str) {
  return str.replace(/(.*)(\s?\-\s?)(.*)/, '$3$2$1');
};

var str = 'Left - Right';
alert('Before is: ' + str);
alert('After is: ' + swap(str));

str = 'Apples-Mangoes';
alert('Before is: ' + str);
alert('After is: ' + swap(str));
```